# Update HP-UX 11i software

Tags: upgrade, hp-ux

I have an old HP-UX 9000/800 PA-RISC B.11.11 (11i) on hands and I'd like to update its services to newer version.

Actually, I'd like to update LD from current version `B.11.18` to `B.11.32`; and Apache-based Web Server from `B.2.0.55.0` to `B.2.0.59.`

How can I do that? I've googled about but there aren't many resources that talk about HP-UX.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the official docs don't contain any information about upgrading stuff. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I'm starting from the scratch because I don't have any official docs from previous person. Then my current situation is I don't know what to look at, if you know there's a book about that, I'm highly appreciated.

Comment: So you haven't even had a look at the official docs on hp.com?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at HP.com but I don't know can I do update a package or system if I don't have support contract, or not? Then, I hope somebody who has knowledge of HP-UX would give advice for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the system under a support contract with HP, you could go to the website and load the upgrade CD and upgrade the system.

Without that you might want to consider using some of the excellent ported public domain software and use gcc and also its apache port.  The site you would checkout is:  http://hpux.connect.org.uk

Comment: unfortunately, the version of HP-UX in the original question, 11.11, is long out of support. Unless you are paying through the nose for an extended support contract, (Which I believe nobody should) your chances of finding 11.11 software update is next to nil. Consider upgrading to 11.23 at the least. I hope your organization have a support contract with HP.